# Entries longer than one row in <td> are centered instead of aligned to the left

Tags: html, css

[image]

As you can see in the picture my problem is, that as long as the content of my `<td>` is only one row the text gets aligned to the left, as I want it to. But as soon the text becomes longer than one row it will be centered for some reason. Adding a `<td style="text-align:left">` produces the same outcome.

How can I fix this, so that the text is always aligned to the left?

Answer (score 0):

This `<td style="text-align:left">` should not be needed. Look if you have any additional style in your table that has an impact on your `<td>`. Text inside of `<td>` is aligned to left as default.

```html
<table>
  <tr>
    <td style="text-align:left"> TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXTTEXT TEXT TEXTTEXT TEXT TEXTTEXT TEXT TEXTTEXT TEXT TEXTTEXT TEXT TEXTTEXT TEXT TEXTTEXT XT TEXT TEXTTEXT TEXT TEXTTEXT TEXT TEXTTEXT TEXT TEXTTEXT TEXT TEXTTEXT TEXT TEXTTEXT TEXT TEXTTEXT TEXT TEXT</td>
    <td> TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXTTEXT TEXT TEXTTEXT TEXT TEXTTEXT TEXT TEXTTEXT TEXT TEXTTEXT TEXT TEXTTEXT TEXT TEXTTEXT TEXT TEXTTEXT TEXT TEXTTEXT TEXT TEXTTEXT TEXT TEXTTEXT TEXT TEXTTEXT TEXT TEXTTEXT TEXT TEXTTEXT TEXT TEXTTEXT TEXT TEXTTEXT TEXT TEXTTEXT TEXT TEXTTEXT TEXTTEXT TEXT TEXTTEXT TEXT TEXT</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Cell C</td>
    <td>Cell D</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```